# Azure Container app job stops execution after 30 minutes

Tags: azure, azure-container-apps, azure-container-app-jobs

I have an azure container app job that fails after running for exactly 30 minutes. Error message in the ContainerAppSystemLogs_CL table within log analytics shows "Job was active longer than specified deadline". Reason being "DeadlineExceeded".

The program is a .NET core console application that basically reads through a gigantic 40 GB json line file sitting on an Azure Data Lake. Each line is a json object within the file. It reads one line at a time using a stream, deserialises it into a C# object and then inserts it into a Azure MYSQL Database. I can see it is inserting the rows into MySQL for 30 minutes successfully but after that the job fails. When I check the logs in azure log analytics, I see the below.

Is there a config that I am missing somewhere where I can increase the job execution time in azure container app job environment?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

While the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/jobs?tabs=azure-portal) does not state a default Replica timeout value, it's set to 30 minutes.

At creation, you can set a different value using the **--replica-timeout** parameter with the CLI. After creation use the Portal, click on the **Configuration menu** to set the Replica timeout value.

Comment: Thank you so much. Believe it or not, I went through those settings and still for some alien reason chose to ignore them. Thank you, one more time !!

Comment: There is another issue that has come up. I increase the replica timeout value to 18000 seconds. The jobs exists successfully after 108 minutes with the system log showing "Container 'XXXXXXX-job' was terminated with exit code '0' and reason 'ProcessExited'". Even though it has a around 500,000 records pending to insert into the database. When I run the same .NET core code on a Windows machine it does it successfully, all records get inserted.